# How to sort a collection from a pagination result

Tags: laravel

I have this collection I have obtained with a pagination query:

```
$apps = $query->paginate(10);
```

The result is something like this:

[image]

I would like to sort this collection before to send it, especially the "data" array. I tried a lot of things with "sortBy" and "sortByDesc". Without success. Each time I use these methods, the pagination is "broken".

How to sort this kind of json obtained by pagination?

Comment: You need to decide if you need the data as a whole sorted; or just the items that are returned as a result of *pagination*. If the first you need to build a query that does the sorting for you (so RDBMS itself does the sorting). You may [find my package](https://github.com/Kyslik/column-sortable) useful for that. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `orderBy`, `orderByDesc` or `orderByRaw` to order the query before paginating the results:

[docs:](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset)

```
$apps = $query->orderBy('created_at')->paginate(10);
```

Comment: hi remul, thanks for the answer. I did not precise but i don't want to use the "orderBy" method of the query. I need to sort the result after the pagination is done.

Comment: Why do you need to sort the result after the pagination? As far as I can tell laravel has no built in support for this.

Comment: I cannot use "orderBy" in my query on some fields. Because these fields are added to the collection after the paginate (and so after the query).

Answer (score 0):

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;


$sortedApps = $query->get()->sortBy('name');

$result = $this->paginateCollection($sortedApps,50);


public function paginateCollection(
    $collection, 
    $perPage, 
    $pageName = 'page', 
    $fragment = null
) : LengthAwarePaginator
    {
        $currentPage = LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage($pageName);
        $currentPageItems = $collection->slice(($currentPage - 1) * $perPage, $perPage);
        parse_str(request()->getQueryString(), $query);
        unset($query[$pageName]);
        $paginator = new LengthAwarePaginator(
            $currentPageItems,
            $collection->count(),
            $perPage,
            $currentPage,
            [
                'pageName' => $pageName,
                'path' => LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPath(),
                'query' => $query,
                'fragment' => $fragment
            ]
        );

        return $paginator;
    }
```